# jQuery Split Button Demo: Is it me or is that just 2 buttons?

Tags: jquery-ui, split-button

Looking at implementing a split-button similar to: the jQuery [SplitButton](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#splitbutton) demo.

Whats the difference between this example and just using 2 buttons? am I missing something?

..particularly regarding the joint "set" demonstrated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's all it is: two buttons that are grouped together. As it states on the webpage -

> *An example of a split button built with two buttons: A plain button with just text, [ and ] one with only a primary icon and no text. Both are grouped together in a set.*

They were just giving us another example of something that could be easily accomplished with the button widget.